# Windows cannot access my external harddisk partition but all partition managers can

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

Some weird problem happened to my Maxtor 500GB external harddisk. It all started when it froze once during some operation. Now when I insert the drive in a USB slot, Windows asks me to format it, and if I try to open the drive from my computer it says, "not accessible"..

I tried most of the major partition managers and partition recovery software.
All of these can see and access my partition normally.
It shows the free space and used space correctly.
But Windows can't read access the disk.

Including a screenshot: On the left side, the partition manager can access and see my data in the corrupted partition, and on the right side Windows can't

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the [Seatools](http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/support/downloads/seatools) diagnostic software. It's from Seagate but they now own Maxtor.

Comment: seatools says everything is fine!!.  but its not..
chkdsk /f driveletter:

fixed it.. now i can access the files normally but only from the computer i run the command with, other computers says the same thing. to format it... its strange. 
now i am copying all the data to a different EHDD, will format it after that.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to repartition it and reformat from Ubuntu LiveCD.